# Subscribe to a queue, receive 1 message, and then unsubscribe

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a scenario where I need to distribute and process jobs extremely quickly.  I'll have about 45 jobs populated in the queue quickly and I can process about 20 simultaneously (5 machines, 4 cores each).  Each job takes a variable amount of time, and to complicate matters garbage collection is an issue so I need to be able to take a consumer offline for garbage collection.

Currently, I have everything working with pop (every consumer pops every 5ms).  This seems undesirable because it translates to 600 pop requests per second to rabbitmq.

I would love if it there were a pop command that would act like subscribe, but for only one message. (the process would block, waiting for input from the rabbitMQ connection, via something akin to Kernel.select)

I have tried to trick the AMQP gem to doing something like this, but it's not working: I can't seem to unsubscribe until the queue is empty and no more messages are being sent to the consumer. Other methods of unsubscribing I fear will lose messages.

consume_1.rb :

```
require "amqp"

EventMachine.run do
  puts "connecting..."
  connection = AMQP.connect(:host => "localhost", :user => "guest", :pass => "guest", :vhost => "/")
  puts "Connected to AMQP broker"

  channel = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
  queue = channel.queue("tasks", :auto_delete => true)
  exchange = AMQP::Exchange.default(channel)

  queue.subscribe do |payload|
    puts "Received a message: #{payload}."
    queue.unsubscribe { puts "unbound" }
    sleep 3
  end
end
```

consumer_many.rb:

```
require "amqp"

# Imagine the command is something CPU - intensive like image processing.
command = "sleep 0.1"

EventMachine.run do
  puts "connecting..."
  connection = AMQP.connect(:host => "localhost", :user => "guest", :pass => "guest", :vhost => "/")
  puts "Connected to AMQP broker"

  channel = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
  queue = channel.queue("tasks", :auto_delete => true)
  exchange = AMQP::Exchange.default(channel)

  queue.subscribe do |payload|
    puts "Received a message: #{payload}."
  end
end
```

producer.rb:

```
require "amqp"

i = 0
EventMachine.run do
  connection = AMQP.connect(:host => "localhost", :user => "guest", :pass => "guest", :vhost => "/")
  puts "Connected to AMQP broker"

  channel = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
  queue = channel.queue("tasks", :auto_delete => true)
  exchange = AMQP::Exchange.default(channel)

  EM.add_periodic_timer(1) do
    msg = "Message #{i}"
    i+=1
    puts "~ publishing #{msg}"
  end
end
```

I'll launch consume_many.rb and producer.rb.  Messages will flow as expected.

When I launch consume_1.rb, it gets every other message (as expected).  But it NEVER unsubscribes because it never finishes processing all of its messages... so on it goes.

How do I get consume_1.rb to subscribe to the queue, get a single message, and then take itself out of the load-balancer ring so it can do it's work, without losing any additional pending jobs that might be in the queue and would otherwise be scheduled to be sent to the process?

Tim

Comment: Writing a server that behaves this way would be stupid-easy in ruby... maybe using zero-mq to implement my own broker is the solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a simple, yet very poorly documented feature of the AMQP gem, what you need is this:

In your consumer:

```
channel = AMQP::Channel.new(connection, :prefetch => 1)
```

And then with your subscribe block, do:

```
queue.subscribe(:ack => true) do |queue_header, payload|
  puts "Received a message: #{payload}."
  # Do long running work here

  # Acknowledge message
  queue_header.ack
end
```

What this does it tells RabbitMQ to only send your consumer 1 message at a time, and not send another message until you call `ack` on the queue header *after* working on a long running task for a while.

I might need to be corrected on this, but I believe a `direct` exchange would be better suited to this task.

Comment: Ivan, you're a genius. I have been searching for this for several months now. THANK YOU!

Comment: I'm not half surprised, I was banging my head against the desk for months before figuring that out from reading the source code.

Comment: Ivan - I don't think the type of exchange would really matter here. His issue is at the queue level because it sounds like he wants multiple consumers working from the same queue, each taking turns to pull a single work item and process it. Therefore, the type of exchange in use doesn't matter because the exchange is essentially out of the picture once the message is inserted into the queue.

Answer (score 1):

With the environment that I have,

RabbitMQ version: 3.3.3

amqp gem version: 1.5.0

The solution from Ivan still resulted in all the messages being fetched from the queue.

Instead, the number of unacknowledged messages by subscribing to a queue can be limited by setting the QoS of a channel.

As per the API document of AMQP::Channel,

```
#qos(prefetch_size = 0, prefetch_count = 32, global = false, &block) ⇒ Object
```

One note for the method in that, if you are running RabbitMQ servers after version 2.3.6, *prefetch_size* is deprecated.

```
channel = AMQP::Channel.new(connection, :prefetch => 1)
channel.qos(0, 1)

queue = channel.queue(queue_name, :auto_delete => false)
queue.subscribe(:ack => true) do |metadata, payload|
  puts "Received a message: #{payload}."

  # Do long running work here

  # Acknowledge message
  metadata.ack
end
```

Hope the solution helps someone out.

Cheers.